# Issue on Instrumentation Profiling for a running cloud service

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2015, azure-worker-roles, instrumentation, azure-cloud-services

we are implementing a data gathering service hosted in a worker role of Azure cloud service,
 we are trying to measure and test the cloud service performance, using the Visual Studio 2015 profiler.

Actually we are stuck on an Issue that we are facing when we use the Instrumentation method, 
 for the remoting profiling: we are unable to read the report and we receive an error related to loading of the symbol.
 The detailed error is :
“DA0002: It appears that the file was collected without properly setting the environment variables with VSPerfCLREnv.cmd. Symbols for managed binaries may not resolve”

We tried this :
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311503

We have followed the instructions for Instrumentation profiling from this pages:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-performance-profiling-cloud-services/

Any idea? Any other experience on profiling with VS (Enterprise) 2015 remote Azure cloud service?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?